# Pure CSS dropdown triggering on hover of wrong element

Tags: html, css

So I have a pure css dropdown menu, but I'm having one problem. The dropdown works when you hover over a link, but it's also triggering when you hover over the actual container that contains the dropdown portion. Here's a jsfiddle with the code. http://jsfiddle.net/9BRac/

```
<div class="nav-con">
  <nav role='navigation' id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="linked"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Link 1.</li>
            <li>Link 2.</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
          </ul>  
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Link 1.</li>
            <li>Link 2.</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
          </ul>  
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Link 1.</li>
            <li>Link 2.</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
          </ul>  
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>


.clearfix:before,  
.clearfix:after {  
    content: " ";  
    display: table;  
}  
.clearfix:after {  
    clear: both;  
}  
.clearfix {  
    *zoom: 1;  
}  

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:black;
  border-bottom: #ffd600 solid 10px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  position:inheirt;
}

nav ul li {
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  width: 80px;
  height:60px;
  margin-left:10px;
  display:;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
  list-style:none;
  position:inherit;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

 nav ul li:hover {
  width: 80px;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  height:60px;
  margin-left:10px;
  background-color:#ffd600;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
  list-style:none;
  position:inherit;
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none;
}

html {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#dropdown {
    width:100%;
  height:200px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color:black;
    display:none;
}


.dropdown {
  margin-top:10px;

}
.dropdown li {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffd600;
}

nav ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
        opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    }

nav ul ul li {
  opacity: 1.0 !important;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
  width: 350px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
/* Your dropdown */
nav ul ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease-in
}

/* Code to display your dropdown */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 0.8;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

For a working example go here http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/9BRac/12/

**Explanation:**
Your `.dropdown` still exists, it just has an `opacity` of `0`.

Whenever you hover over this “invisible” `.dropdown` you trigger the hover styling for its parent `li`, which leads to showing `.dropdown` again.

The solution: set a `visibility` of `hidden` for your `.dropdown`, and set the `visibility` to `visible` only when you hover over the parent `li`

Also only use the transition on the `opacity` property, then `visibility` is changed immediately, but the `opacity` transitions smoothly.

PS: If you're curious why I'm not using `display:none`, it is because you can't transition display ([source for the solution using `visibiliy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `visibility:hidden` instead of editing just the opacity on hover like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9BRac/18/

Now you can edit a bit the transitions timing to make it smoother.

As well the transition property could be used on opacity only and not on all properties.